# How can I overlay values on flextable minibars?

Tags: r, flextable

The closest I can get with flextable is this:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is something like this - knocked up with ggplot2:

[image]

Any ideas? or is this a feature request?

Code used to generate flextable:

```
library(tibble)
library(flextable)


tib <- tibble(v1 = letters[1:4],
              v2 = c(1, 3, 5, 2))


tib %>% 
  flextable()%>% 
  width(j = 1:2, width = c(0.5, 1.5)) %>% 
  mk_par(j = 2,
         value = as_paragraph(as_chunk(v2, formater = function(x) sprintf("%.0f", x)),
                              " ",
                              minibar(value = v2, max = sum(v2))
                              ),
  part = "body")
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to make a ggplot function for use in the flextable:

```
tib <- tibble(v1 = letters[1:4], v2 = c(1, 3, 5, 2))

gg_bar <- function(z, y_lim = NA) {
  if (is.na(y_lim)) { vy_lim <- c(0, z) } else { vy_lim <- c(0, y_lim) }
  z <- data.frame(x = 1, z = z, w = z) 
  
  ggplot(z, aes(x = x, y = z)) + geom_col(fill = "#B4D5FF") +
    geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = w), hjust = 0, size = 6) + 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = vy_lim)+ coord_flip() + theme_void()
}

tib <- tib %>% mutate( v2 = lapply(v2, gg_bar, y_lim = max(v2)) )

tib %>% 
  flextable()%>% 
  width(j = 1:2, width = c(0.5, 1.5)) %>% 
  mk_par(j = 2, value = as_paragraph(gg_chunk(value = ., height = .45, width = 1)), use_dot = TRUE )
```